# pipe command together

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I need to pipe 2 commands together, the first command replaced XYZ in input file to ",", then I need to do do another replace. unsuccessfully tried the following.

`tr 'XYZ' ',' <input_file | xargs tr ',' ''`

what's the right way to pipe two command together where the second command expects input from a file?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but why do two calls to `tr`? Why not do `tr 'XYZ' ''`?

Comment: @squiguy - Consider the input `A,B,C XYZ D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tr 'XYZ' ',' <input_file | tr ',' ''
```

The pipe symbol `|` connects the standard output of the first command to the standard input of the 2nd command. `tr` is a *filter*, that is a program that expects its input to appear on the standard input stream and emits its result on the standard output stream.

You can connect as many of these together as you want:

```
tr 'A' 'B' < input_file | tr 'C' 'D' | tr 'E' 'F' | tr 'Z' 'Q'
```

Comment: `cat input_file | tr 'XYZ' ',' | tr ',' '' `

Comment: If you think so `cat` is always useless. In this case cat makes the command is more readable, left-to-right pipes all the way down.

Comment: Nope. There are several perfectly valid uses of cat, some of which are listed on the page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the characters deleted then the -d flag to tr will do that no need to replace with `''`

```
tr -d 'xyz' < file
```

will display the contents of file on stdout with all x's y's and z's deleted